# Put fixed row on each scroll div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some div that contains Logo + labels + arrow. I will retrieve with json so I will don't know the exact number. What I want to do is to align horizontally logo+labels+arrow, and add a scroll bar if the labels will overflow-x. The arrow must be always visible, and be on the bottom of the div. What am I doing wrong?

```css
    body {
       font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
     color: #89867e;
     background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .wrapper {
     margin: 20px;
     padding: 2em;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-weight: 300;
     max-height: 388px; 
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
        background-color: #ccc;
        margin-bottom:25px;
    }

    .internal {
      display: inline; 
     height: 164px;
     padding: .4em 1em; 
     border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     -webkit-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     -moz-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     -o-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     color: rgba(249, 249, 249, .9);
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-weight: 300;
     margin-right: 18px;
    }
 

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+1) { background: #e87352; }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+2) { background: #ebc85e; }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+3) { background: #3bbec0; }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+4) { background: #4ad585; }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+5) { background: rgb(27, 54, 71); }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+6) { background: rgb(21, 40, 54); }
 

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+1) { background: rgb(208, 101, 3); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+2) { background: rgb(233, 147, 26); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+3) { background: rgb(22, 145, 190); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+4) { background: rgb(22, 107, 162); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+5) { background: rgb(27, 54, 71); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+6) { background: rgb(21, 40, 54); }

    .trasparente {
      background: transparent !important;
     padding: 0;
     border:none;
    }

    .logo {
     max-width: 318px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin-right: 18px;
    }

/* arrow */
.arrow-wrap {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    left:50%;
    padding: 15px 15px !important;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin-left:-5em;
    background:#111 !important;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    padding:4em 2em;
    border-radius:50%;
 -webkit-border-radius:50%;
 -moz-border-radius:50%;
 -o-border-radius:50%;
    font-size:.6em;
    display:block;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #333;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #333;
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #333;
 -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #333;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.arrow {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
    left: -6px;
    top: 25px;
 border-style: solid;
 -webkit-border-style: solid;
 -moz-border-style: solid;
 -o-border-style: solid;
 border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -webkit-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -moz-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -o-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
 -webkit-border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
 -moz-border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
 -o-border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

.arrow:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left: -43px;  
    top: -46.8px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
 -webkit-border-style: solid;
 -moz-border-style: solid;
 -o-border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -webkit-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -moz-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -o-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
    border-color: #111 transparent transparent transparent;
 -webkit-border-color: #111 transparent transparent transparent;
 -moz-border-color: #111 transparent transparent transparent;
 -o-border-color: #111 transparent transparent transparent;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrows {
    0% { top:0; }
    10% { top:12%; }
    20% { top:0; }
    30% { top:12%; }
    40% { top:-12%; }
    50% { top:12%; }
    60% { top:0; }
    70% { top:12%; }
    80% { top:-12%; }
    90% { top:12%; }
    100% { top:0; }
}
 
.arrow-wrap .arrow {
 animation: arrows 2.8s 0.4s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation: arrows 2.8s 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
} 

.w { position: relative; }
```

```html
     <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="internal trasparente"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/bar/8/86/744px-Siemens-logo_svg.png" class="logo" style="margin-top:20px" alt="logo"></a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 1</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 2</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 3</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 4</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 5</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 6</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 7</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 8</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 9</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 10</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 11</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 12</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 13</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 14</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 15</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 16</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 17</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 18</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 19</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 20</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 21</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 22</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 23</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 24</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 25</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 26</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 27</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 28</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 29</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 30</a>      
    <!-- ARROW -->
       <div class="w">
 <a class="arrow-wrap" href="#">
   <span class="arrow"></span> 
 </a>       
         </div>
    </div> <!-- end wapper -->

    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="internal trasparente"><img src="http://www.asborsoniww.com/media/tes_logo.png" class="logo" style="margin-top:20px" alt="logo"></a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 1</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 2</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 3</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 4</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 5</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 6</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 7</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 8</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 9</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 10</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 11</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 12</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 13</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 14</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 15</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 16</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 17</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 18</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 19</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 20</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 21</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 22</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 23</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 24</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 25</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 26</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 27</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 28</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 29</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 30</a>      
    <!-- ARROW -->
    <div class="w">
   <a class="arrow-wrap" href="#">
     <span class="arrow"></span> 
   </a>       
    </div>
    </div> <!-- end wapper -->

    <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="" class="internal">item 1</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 2</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 3</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 4</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 5</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 6</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 7</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 8</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 9</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 10</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 11</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 12</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 13</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 14</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 15</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 16</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 17</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 18</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 19</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 20</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 21</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 22</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 23</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 24</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 25</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 26</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 27</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 28</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 29</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 30</a>
     
    <!-- ARROW -->
      <div class="w">
 <a class="arrow-wrap" href="#">
   <span class="arrow"></span> 
 </a>       
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end wapper -->
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take out an arrow HTML from `wrapper` class. (so it will attach to the parent not list itself).

```css
    body {
       font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
     color: #89867e;
     background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    .wrapper {
     margin: 20px;
     padding: 2em;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-weight: 300;
     max-height: 388px; 
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
        background-color: #ccc;
        margin-bottom:25px;
    }

    .internal {
      display: inline; 
     height: 164px;
     padding: .4em 1em; 
     border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     -webkit-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     -moz-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     -o-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
     color: rgba(249, 249, 249, .9);
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-weight: 300;
     margin-right: 18px;
    }
 

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+1) { background: #e87352; }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+2) { background: #ebc85e; }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+3) { background: #3bbec0; }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+4) { background: #4ad585; }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+5) { background: rgb(27, 54, 71); }

    .wrapper a:nth-child(6n+6) { background: rgb(21, 40, 54); }
 

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+1) { background: rgb(208, 101, 3); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+2) { background: rgb(233, 147, 26); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+3) { background: rgb(22, 145, 190); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+4) { background: rgb(22, 107, 162); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+5) { background: rgb(27, 54, 71); }

    .wrapper:nth-child(6n+6) { background: rgb(21, 40, 54); }

    .trasparente {
      background: transparent !important;
     padding: 0;
     border:none;
    }

    .logo {
     max-width: 318px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin-right: 18px;
    }

/* arrow */
.arrow-wrap {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    left:50%;
    padding: 15px 15px !important;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin-left:-5em;
    background:#111 !important;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    padding:4em 2em;
    border-radius:50%;
 -webkit-border-radius:50%;
 -moz-border-radius:50%;
 -o-border-radius:50%;
    font-size:.6em;
    display:block;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #333;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #333;
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #333;
 -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #333;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.arrow {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
    left: -6px;
    top: 25px;
 border-style: solid;
 -webkit-border-style: solid;
 -moz-border-style: solid;
 -o-border-style: solid;
 border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -webkit-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -moz-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -o-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
 -webkit-border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
 -moz-border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
 -o-border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

.arrow:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left: -43px;  
    top: -46.8px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
 -webkit-border-style: solid;
 -moz-border-style: solid;
 -o-border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -webkit-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -moz-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
 -o-border-width: 3em 3em 0 3em;
    border-color: #111 transparent transparent transparent;
 -webkit-border-color: #111 transparent transparent transparent;
 -moz-border-color: #111 transparent transparent transparent;
 -o-border-color: #111 transparent transparent transparent;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrows {
    0% { top:0; }
    10% { top:12%; }
    20% { top:0; }
    30% { top:12%; }
    40% { top:-12%; }
    50% { top:12%; }
    60% { top:0; }
    70% { top:12%; }
    80% { top:-12%; }
    90% { top:12%; }
    100% { top:0; }
}
 
.arrow-wrap .arrow {
 animation: arrows 2.8s 0.4s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation: arrows 2.8s 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
} 

.w { position: relative; }
```

```html
     <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="internal trasparente"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/bar/8/86/744px-Siemens-logo_svg.png" class="logo" style="margin-top:20px" alt="logo"></a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 1</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 2</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 3</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 4</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 5</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 6</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 7</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 8</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 9</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 10</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 11</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 12</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 13</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 14</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 15</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 16</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 17</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 18</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 19</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 20</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 21</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 22</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 23</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 24</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 25</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 26</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 27</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 28</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 29</a>
      <a href="" class="internal">item 30</a>           
         </div>
    <!-- ARROW -->
       <div class="w">
 <a class="arrow-wrap" href="#">
   <span class="arrow"></span> 
 </a>  
    </div> <!-- end wapper -->
```